# Spring boot JPA application NOT working with HikariCP configuration

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp, tomcat-jdbc

We have configured our spring boot(v1.5.1)-jpa application to point to HikariCP but still due to some weird reason the application is still pointing to tomcat-jdbc pool, the default used by spring-boot instead of Hikari-CP.
I have mentioned the configuration used below.

**Updates**
After making changes now when the HikariCP is trying to load we are getting the SQLNotSupportedFeature Exception. 
Do note that we are using Springboot-JPA-Hibernate combination along with hikari.

Any help is appreciated.

**Gradle**

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP
    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.3.2'

    // Exclusions
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    //spring integration
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration"){
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
hibernate.show.sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=pooool
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:1521/<instance>
spring.datasource.username=<user>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

**Dataconfiguration**

We are using Spring JPA hibernate combination for configuration along with PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry).

```
        public class DataSourceConfiguration {

            @Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size}")
            private int maxSize;

            @Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout}")
            private String idleTimeout;

            @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
            private String username;

            @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
            private String password;

            @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
            private String url;

            @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
            private String driverClassName;

            @Bean("destroyMethod=close")
            @Primary
            public DataSource dataSource() {
                HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
                dataSource.setUrl(url);
                dataSource.setPassword(password);
                dataSource.setUsername(username);
                dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
                dataSource.setValidationQuery(idleTimeout);
                dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxSize);
                return dataSource;
            }

            @Bean
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
                System.err.println("POOLSIZE----> " +dataSource.getPoolSize());
                System.err.println("POOLNAME----> " +dataSource.getName());
                    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
                    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(applicationPropertiesConfig.getPackagestoScan());

                    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
                    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", applicationPropertiesConfig.getHibernateDialect());
                    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", applicationPropertiesConfig.getHibernateShowSQL());
                    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
                    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
            }

            /**
             * Declaration of the transaction manager.
             *
             * @param entityManagerFactory the entity manager factory
             * @return an instance of JpaTransactionManager
             */
            @Bean
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
                    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
                    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
                    return transactionManager;
            }
```

Please help as this is blocking our application and is frustrating. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am assuming you have Hikari-CP in your dependencies correct? Make sure you expelicitly exclude tomcat-jdbc from the POM. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-mysql-hikaricp-example/

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it earlier. yes we did add exclusions but it is of no use.

Comment: After comparing your project with one of my own that I know is working with HikaryCP. The only different I see is that you do not have a driver in the pom. Maybe that is not being picked up. Try adding this dependency 
compile group: 'oracle', name: 'ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.3'

Comment: Thanks will try this and let you know. We also suspected this since we are getting the SqlNotsuppoertedFeature Exception when hikari is trying to load itself

Comment: what's your Hibernate version?

Comment: We are using hibernate 5.0+ version jars along with spring boot starter jpa as a wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You should `new HikariDataSource(.....)` instead of `new DataSource()` in your bean.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However if i do that will it not be "hard coding". I want to keep my code flexible. Say tomorrow if we want to switch from Hikari to Tomcat or some-other pool i expect to change only the config files without touching the code. We will also lose the advantage of {spring.datasource.type} that is provided by spring. According to documentation just mentioning the type and configuring the properties is enough. is this a bug faced by all ?

Comment: So it is better to add your requirements in your question. And maybe replace the pool is really not a real requirement.

Comment: we tried your suggestion, however we are getting the SQLFeatureNotSupportedException we tried the oracle driver name: 'ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.3', ojdbc7 etc but still keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle should have following config for hikari:

```
configurations {
     compile.exclude module: "tomcat-jdbc"
}

dependencies {
     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
     compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.6.3'
}
```

Above will exclude tomcat-jdbc and will create connection pool using hikari. Hope this will help.